# Add 5 kilometer to latitude and longitude

Tags: android, flutter, q

I am facing a problem I don't how to do that. Suppose I have 20 users in the city so I want to find the nearest user to me with in a range of 5 kilometres. Actually, I am building an app using firebase where I can find the nearest blood donor. How can I find it? Need suggestion. if I add 5 kilometres to latitude and longitude from all side. Is it possible and Am I on the right track? if yes so how would I add 5 kilometres to latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the geodesy library to calculate distances between locations.

https://pub.dev/packages/geodesy

```
num distance = geodesy.distanceBetweenTwoGeoPoints(l1, l2);
```

Note -- since the earth's surface is not flat (although some still believe that) you cannot use simple euclidian geometry to calculate the distance.